# wso2 EI: custom datasource

Tags: wso2-esb

We are using multi tenants on the same EI for different environments. 
We have different endpoints for each environment. I have created different datasources in the custom-datasource.xml for each environment(Dev, QA, etc.,).

Some of the calls are stored procedure calls and the other are direct queries.

I have written a custom class having the below piece of code to connect to the database and to call a stored procedure.

```
String driverClassName = "***.**.DriverclassName";       
String databaseUrl = "***url***";
localDbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, "UserName", "PASSWORD");
```

Now my problem here is,

1. I have to put the above environment specific database connection string values in a common place. I should be able to use them for all the procedure calls across all the environments. Please let me know how to do this.
2. I have added the datasource for each environment in custom-datasource.xml. Mounting it in the registry.xml is enough ? how will the environment specific configurations works ?

Comment: Could you please explain your requirement bit more. It is not clear what are you trying to do and what issue you are facing.

Comment: @Rans, I have edited my question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dataservice](http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/09/writing-data-service-to-execute-stored.html) to connect to a carbon datasource defined (may be as a custom datasource) and query a stored procedure. If this does not help, please elaborate more on your requirement.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks.